# Word completion ^P / ^N is very slow because of scanning a :term buffer

Tags: terminal-buffer, ins-completion

I open a terminal window inside of a vim session and leave it there for weeks, use it for compilation, running and debugging my code. After couple of days the length of the  terminal buffer grows over many millions of lines, which is not a problem at all. The problematic part is: these millions of lines (junk mostly) are scanned for key words when I use word completion (`^P`) in any other buffer.

The question is: is there any way to explicitly exclude terminal buffers from scanning for `^P`/`^N` completion?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a way to exclude terminal buffers from completion. But you can reduce `termwinscroll` value, which sets the number of scrollback lines to keep. Since the lines evicted from the scrollback are unloaded from memory, they will not be used for completion.

To see what's your current value, issue `:se twsl?`. To have a maximum of 1000 lines in the scrollback, use

```
:se twsl=1000
```

Comment: The value 'termwinscroll=1000000' works fine. Thanks! a good workaround.